# Common app state architecture for Java/Kotlin Android apps?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, kotlin, redux

What is most used pattern for managing state in Java or Kotlin Android apps?

I am moving to Kotlin from React Native, where I used literally just React Redux architecture.

What is the most common used architecture nowadays? I doubt that Android apps in 2020 still using per Component state with bidirectional communication as I was doing it before I learned Redux in React.

Comment: You store the state locally in your view or Activity.  App state has never really taken off as a pattern anywhere but in React programming.  Mainly because it isn't needed.  The main reason its used in React is because its a workaround to a flaw in the platform (that flaw being that there is no layer outside the UI to control and store state).  That's not the case here.  If you need state between activities, there's a variety of solutions depending on where/why you need it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you some opinionated pointers.

A relatively simple architecture is MVVM where you have a viewModel to hold your state during configuration changes. It integrates well with Architecture components, and that should make your life easy, having the Android lifecycle in mind.

A more complex and powerful approach is RxJava. You can use the database as a central source of truth, and all data flow will go through it. I know it sounds bad, but the performance is OK. Everything is done async. It's a good solution for a complex app, but probably an overkill for a small one. The learning curve with Rx will be steeper, but many people love it for a reason.

You can also use Kotlin Coroutines Flow instead of Rx, and couple it with MVVM. It's less powerful than RxJava at the moment, as far as I know, but it's a bit easier to understand, and results in less boilerplate.

Additionally, you can shape it more like MVI. You can split your app into layers - UI, business logic, API, persistence. You can isolate them by delivering all data through actions and results. This means you'll have separate classes for holding data on every layer. It makes things clean, but can be an overkill for a small app. You can achieve this both with Rx and Flow.

Don't use MVP, it has a lot of inherent issues. I don't think you should look into MVC either. Flutter is too young. I generally avoid solutions maintained by companies, like MvRx by Airbnb, but if you're open to the idea there are a few interesting ones.

You can use Dagger2 for dependency injection, it's even documented by Google. Or look into Koin, which is simpler though possibly less powerful.

Regarding the UI, I like the idea of declarative UI. But this is a transition period for me - I'm looking forward to a stable version of Jetpack Compose. But until then I'm stuck with the old UI stack based on Views. You could look into Litho by Facebook or something similar, but as I said, I'm wary of using tools by such companies when there's something coming from Google / Jetbrains behind the corner.

You can use ViewBinding to reference your views.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of patterns in android applications develoment
You can read about it here:
https://blog.mindorks.com/mastering-design-patterns-in-android-with-kotlin
You have to choose the best pattern for each project individually. 
For States managment I suggest you to use the "Model View Controller" also called MVC